# Sending Firebase Cloud Message to closed App does not work

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying some things with Firebase Cloud Messaging and i got to the point, where i can use the FCM-Console to send messages to devices via FCM token. I thought you can receive those messages even when your app isnt running completely. But i can just receive those messages when my App is running in the background.

My Question is now, is it possible to receive Messages when your app is not running and if yes how do i accomplish this?

Here is what i have added to manifest:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/app_icon" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />


    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and in classes:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    //if the message contains data payload
    //It is a map of custom keyvalues
    //we can read it easily
    if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
        //handle the data message here
    }

    //getting the title and the body
    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
}
}


public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService{
//private Socket mSocket;

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();

    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    Log.d("MyRefreshedToken", token);

    storeToken(token);
}

private void storeToken(String token) {
    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).saveDeviceToken(token);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to receive messages with your onMessageReceived-method when your app isn't running. To do this you need to send a data message, also known as a silent push message. This means that you need to omit notification title and body properties, and only send information with the data property.

Ex.

```
{
  "message": {
    "token":"78yadsbjbasjkdjbkasbdjkbak...",
    "data": {
      "Topic" : "Data message",
      "Content" : "This message should be handled by onMessageReceived regardless if the app is running or not.",
    }
  }
}
```

For more information check out the following pages from the Firebase docs:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: Alright, so the app would get the data, but the user would not see the notification directly? I want to send the user a push notification even when the app is closed. Is that possible with FCM?

Comment: You can create your own notification inside your onMessageReceived-method and the user will receive it as a normal push notification.

Take a look at the doc's for creating a notification.
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification